# A test consists of 5 true-false questions. How many different possible answer sequences are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm studying for a statistics exam next week. Have lots of questions.

A test consists of 5 true-false questions. How many different possible answer sequences are there?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your attempt on this problem and you will be more likely to receive positive responses.

Comment: Try answering the question if there is one question, two questions, three questions.  Look for a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have one question, there are two possible answers, so let's say $a_1=2$ then $a_2 =4 = (2*2)$, $a_3 = 8=(2*2*2)$, here we can notice $a_n = 2^n$, so $a_5=32$

Comment: Thank you so much @Ruben Kruepper

Answer (score 2):

Number of ways to answer five true/false questions =

Number of ways to answer the first four questions and answer the last question TRUE +

Number of ways to answer the first four questions and answer the last question FALSE.

=========

The above answer is serious.  This gives you enough information to completely figure out the answer.